# Error in sample.int(m, k) : cannot take a sample larger than the population

Tags: r, machine-learning, data-mining, k-means, text-mining

First, let me say that I'm fairly new to Machine Learning, kmeans, and r, and this project is a means to learn more about this and also to present this data to our CIO so I can use it in the development of a new help desk system.

I have a 60K line text file. The file contains the titles of help desk tickets entered in by teachers over a 3 year period.

I would like create a r program that takes these titles and creates a set of categories. For instance, terms related to printing issues, or a group of terms related to projector bulbs. I have used r to open the text document, clean up the data, remove stop words and other words that I felt were not necessary. I've gotten a list of all the terms with a frequency >= 400 and saved those to a text file.

But now I want to apply (if it can be done or is appropriate) kmeans clustering to that same data set and see if I can come up with categories.

The code below includes code that will write out the list of terms used >= 400. It is at the end, and is commented out.

```
library(tm) #load text mining library
library(SnowballC)
options(max.print=5.5E5) 
setwd('c:/temp/') #sets R's working directory to near where my files are
ae.corpus<-Corpus(DirSource("c:/temp/"),readerControl=list(reader=readPlain))
summary(ae.corpus) #check what went in
ae.corpus <- tm_map(ae.corpus, tolower)
ae.corpus <- tm_map(ae.corpus, removePunctuation)
ae.corpus <- tm_map(ae.corpus, removeNumbers)
ae.corpus <- tm_map(ae.corpus, stemDocument, language = "english")  
myStopwords <- c(stopwords('english'), <a very long list of other words>)
ae.corpus <- tm_map(ae.corpus, removeWords, myStopwords) 

ae.corpus <- tm_map(ae.corpus, PlainTextDocument)

ae.tdm <- DocumentTermMatrix(ae.corpus, control = list(minWordLength = 5))


dtm.weight <- weightTfIdf(ae.tdm)

m <- as.matrix(dtm.weight)
rownames(m) <- 1:nrow(m)

#euclidian 
norm_eucl <- function(m) {
  m/apply(m,1,function(x) sum(x^2)^.5)
}
m_norm <- norm_eucl(m)

results <- kmeans(m_norm,25)

#list clusters

clusters <- 1:25
for (i in clusters){
  cat("Cluster ",i,":",findFreqTerms(dtm.weight[results$cluster==i],400,"\n\n"))
}


#inspect(ae.tdm)
#fft <- findFreqTerms(ae.tdm, lowfreq=400)

#write(fft, file = "dataTitles.txt",
#      ncolumns = 1,
#      append = FALSE, sep = " ")

#str(fft)

#inspect(fft)
```

When I run this using RStudio, I get:

```
> results <- kmeans(m_norm,25)
```

> Error in sample.int(m, k) : cannot take a sample larger than the population when 'replace = FALSE'

I'm not really sure what this means, and I haven't found a lot of info about this online. Any thoughts?

TIA

Comment: Is `m_norm` big enough for 25 centers?

Comment: I dropped it to 5 centers and got the same error. When I dropped it to 2, I got

    'Error in do_one(nmeth) : NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 1)'

Comment: Since you're new to programming as well as `R`, may I suggest you start small?  Create a 10-line file with appropriate data so you know in advance what the result should be. Run that step-by-step to verify you are applying the correct algorithms.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft, I did that. I used 10 and 100 using kmeans(m_norm,2) and got the same error. When I dropped it to kmeans(m_norm,1) I got "Error in do_one(nmeth) : NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 1)". 

It may be that I'm just flat out doing something wrong or trying to use this in the wrong way...I've watched a couple of youtube videos and put together code trying to make this work...

Comment: What shape does `m_norm` have? Did any of the operations destroy your data maybe?

Answer (score 0):

You are reading single file with multiple lines instead of multiple files in a directory. Instead of

```
ae.corpus<-Corpus(DirSource("c:/temp/"),readerControl=list(reader=readPlain))`
```

you need to use

```
text <- readLines("c:\\temp\\your_file_name", n = -1)
ae.corpus<-Corpus(VectorSource(text),readerControl=list(reader=readPlain))
```

Then your will get a corpus with 60K files instead of 1 files with 60k lines.

Comment: Even i am facing same issue. I have only 1000 rows in my text. Same error

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem,finally I find the target number of clusters is larger than the data row of some types. Because the data of each types in your way may be less than the target number of clusters.